# Kotlin: Check which button was clicked

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, button

I have 3 buttons that call the same method, within the method I'd like to be able to retrieve either the button's text or ID.

Is there something like this?

```
 fun getButtonID(view: View) {

        var buttonTxt = this.getText
        Log.d("DEV", "${buttonTxt}")

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onClickListener`s pass the clicked `View` to their callback, so you can do this kind of thing to identify it:

```
fun handleButtonClick(view: View) {
    with (view as Button) {
        Log.d("TAG", "$text, $id")
    }
}
```

and then set your buttons up like

```
button1.setOnClickListener { view ->
    handleButtonClick(view)
}
```

That's one way to cast the `View` to `Button` - by doing it in the handler method you only do it in one place. And since your `onClick` lambda is only calling the method and passing the parameter straight in (no need to cast it as well), it means you can simplify it to a function reference, since your function takes the same arguments the lambda did (i.e. just a `View`):

```
button1.setOnClickListener(::handleButtonClick)
```

and while we're at it

```
listOf(button1, button2, button3).forEach {
    it.setOnClickListener(::handleButtonClick)
}
```

Comment: By the way, you can just call the `handleButtonClick()` method using the onClick attriubte in the XML of the button (that you way you don't have to setup the click listeners)

Comment: Yeah! You have a few options - it's good to know the general code version though, it pops up a lot (with other events, and things like setting up the button handler on a ``Dialog``)